# chrome behaves diffrently for "item" value

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have an HTML tag

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Add an item" name="item"></input>
```

now the strange thing is a prediction list appears only in chrome, but doesn't appear for any other value of name attribute or any other browser.

can anyone explain me what does `name = "item"` have in special???

Comment: It's likely because you've entered values into another website's field, also named item, in the past. Also, you shouldn't close the input element.

Comment: Closing the input isn't bad practice necessarily, however, consider doing it like so: `<input type="text" placeholder="Add an item" name="item" />`. Goggle Chrome generally saves specific data for auto-fills etc. for things it has "experienced before". So your Google Chrome has probably dealt with the *name="item"* property before.

Comment: yeah, I had a website with a name value as item
thanks, that helps